# Can schemas be used in a product where the sending address is configurable

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-admin-sdk

Not a dev question but since this is where the docs point I'm asking it here, hopefully won't be closed. ;)

Given this line in https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google :

> Emails must come from a static email address, eg foo@bar.com

I take it there's no way to make use of Schemas yet in a product where users configure their own mail server and from address?

If that is correct, are there any plans to allow schemas to work in this sort of environment in the future?

We'd love to bake it into our product's emails but seems like we can't with this constraint since each install sends emails from it's own configured 'from' address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only static email addresses are supported in this initial rollout, but we might reconsider this decision in the future. Please fill the form at https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google to describe your use case anyway and tell us why you have this requirement.